# c# Windows Store - Service between pages

Tags: c#, service, windows-runtime, windows-store

I'm building an app that should always be running. Every day i should check online if the licence is still good. So every day for example at 10.00 the app should try the connection to a web server and retrieve some information from it.
Now i would like to know if there is any way to instantiate a service running through apps and inside my app through pages.
Is that possible? Any tips about how to menage this issue?

Comment: could this be a solution? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27411

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a `BackgroundTask` can be registered by an app to be scheduled when it is suspended. It certainly can't iterate over multiple apps. I'm not sure what exactly you mean by iterating through pages, but you could retrieve some information from your server and store locally or update a tile for example.